# Google CloudSQL - cannot delete created role

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11, google-cloud-sql

I created user *observer* using only **postgres** user on my PostgreSQL 11 instance and I don't need it anymore. But after all I can't delete it - pgAdmin showing me that my user have **connect** privileges granted by the **cloudsqlsuperuser**, and I cannot revoke it to delete my earlier created  user account!

```
somebase=> REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "somebase" FROM observer;
REVOKE
somebase=> DROP ROLE observer;
ERROR:  role "observer" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:  privileges for database somebase
```

I tried to delete it using gcloud cli and CloudSQL console both and failed. 
So how to delete it now?

Comment: Have you managed to find a workaround?